# Debounce computed properties/getters in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, vuex

I can't seem to debounce (lodash) computed properties or vuex getters. The debounced functions always return undefined.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/yqk0jp1j/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="text">
  <div>computed: {{ textComputed }} </div>
  <div>debounced: {{ textDebounced }} </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  data:{
    text:''
  },
  computed:{
    textDebounced: _.debounce(function(){
      return this.text
    },500),
    textComputed(){
        return this.text
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: Are you open to alternative solutions or are you requiring that debounce applies to the computed item?

Comment: Well i'd like to know why it doesn't work, but yeah sure what kind of alternative solution do you have?

Comment: See this interesting fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yqk0jp1j/3/

Comment: Debouncing is a way of controlling how often a function is called. It is asynchronous in nature and cannot return a value. That is why it cannot be used for a computed.

Comment: What exactly were you trying to attempt here? `_.debounce` does not have any return value on its own, so of course you see undefined as the result. The debounced return value inside the inner functions is just thrown away.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, debouncing is an inherently asynchronous operation, and so cannot return a value. Depending on your needs, you might want to debounce on the *input* side. There will be no difference between the value in `text` and that in `textComputed`, but if you `v-model="textComputed"`, the value setting will be debounced.

If you specifically want a debounced version of a variable, **mrogers** has given a good solution.

```js
var x = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'start'
  },
  computed: {
    textComputed: {
      get() {
        return this.text;
      },
      set: _.debounce(function(newValue) {
        this.text = newValue;
      }, 500)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Debounced input:
    <input v-model="textComputed">
  </div>
  <div>
    Immediate input:
    <input v-model="text">
  </div>
  <div>computed: {{ textComputed }} </div>
  <div>debounced: {{ text }} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mainly wanted to know why it doesn't work, thanks. I'm not debouncing an input, that was just my example, i just wanted to delay a computed property value somehow.

Comment: Do you have a recommended way of doing this for Vuex? (e.g. using two-way binding on store value, with set calling a commit? set calling an action and having the action debounce the commit?)

Comment: @SumNeuron It just depends on what you're trying to achieve. With Vuex, actions can by asynchronous, so you could debounce in there. Mutations must be synchronous, so not there.

Comment: @RoyJ I have a text field which, upon changing, toggles a calculation which takes a while... in toy example, not an issue, but doesnt scale well with normal human typing speed... so probably better to debounce the store's state which is current 2-way form bound to the text input...

Comment: You might use [.lazy](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy) instead, but yes, you can debounce the setting action.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any insight as to why the debounce function doesn't work on a computed property.  However, an alternative solution is to put the debounce on a function in the `methods` section and call it via a `watch`.

https://jsfiddle.net/vsc4npv3/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<input v-model="text">
<div>computed: {{ textComputed }} </div>
<div>debounced: {{ debouncedText }} </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var x = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  data:{
    text:'',
    debouncedText: ''
  },
  watch: {
    text: function (val) {
        this.debouncer();
    }
  },
  computed:{
    textComputed(){
        return this.text;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    debouncer: _.debounce(function(){
      this.debouncedText = this.text;
    },500)
  }

})
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Simple
2. No external dependencies (like `_.debounce`)
3. Tailored for Vue

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

// Thanks to https://github.com/vuejs-tips/v-debounce/blob/master/debounce.js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timeoutID = null
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID)
    var args = arguments
    var that = this
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(that, args)
    }, delay)
  }
}

function debouncedProperty(delay) {
  let observable = Vue.observable({ value: undefined });
  return {
    get() { return observable.value; },
    set: debounce(function (newValue) { observable.value = newValue; }, delay)
  }
}

// component
export default {
  computed: {
    myProperty: debouncedProperty(300),
  },
}
```