# What is sane way in vuejs + vuex form handling?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuex

I have a large forms to submit in single page.

```
<container>
  <formA>
  <formB>
  <formC>
  <submitButton>
<container>
```

it looks apparently like this. and I have a store which save every form data. then when user click submit button, I gather all form data using vuex store.

The problem is I need to update the form data in store everytime.

so I'll be like this in vue component

```
 watch: {
   userInput (val) {
     this.updateState(val)
 }
```

update state when input changes by watching form data(binded with v-model).

or like this which is documented in vuex doc.

```
  userInput: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.userInput
    },
    set (val) {
      this.updateState(val)
    }
  }
```

well.. I don't think these are good idea. Is there any better way to form handling with vuex?

Comment: What about those ideas is not good?

Comment: I faced a similar problem. It just doesn't make sense to update the store on every input. Imo, the store should just receive the submitted form data. So keep a local copy of the form data in your form component, and on successful submit, make a commit to the store with the form data.

Comment: @RoyJ code is redundant and watching every input is not good for performance.

Comment: @EricGuan I need to get latest data from the form components. That's why I store the data everytime.

Comment: Would you like it better if you could [debounce the inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772629/debounce-computed-properties-getters-in-vue/44780866#44780866)? Or use the `change` event rather than the `input` event to update the variables and store?

Comment: @RoyJ That seems better idea. but I managed with the solution which is object reference. https://jsfiddle.net/mj111/7bL0qw2z/  it's kind of hack.. but it suits for my circumstance

Answer (score 12):

I made a little tool which makes form handling wit Vuex a lot easier: [vuex-map-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields)

### Example

#### Store

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

// Import the `getField` getter and the `updateField`
// mutation function from the `vuex-map-fields` module.
import { getField, updateField } from 'vuex-map-fields';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fieldA: '',
    fieldB: '',
  },
  getters: {
    // Add the `getField` getter to the
    // `getters` of your Vuex store instance.
    getField,
  },
  mutations: {
    // Add the `updateField` mutation to the
    // `mutations` of your Vuex store instance.
    updateField,
  },
});
```

#### Component

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input v-model="fieldA">
    <input v-model="fieldB">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields';

export default {
  computed: {
    // The `mapFields` function takes an array of
    // field names and generates corresponding
    // computed properties with getter and setter
    // functions for accessing the Vuex store.
    ...mapFields([
      'fieldA',
      'fieldB',
    ]),
  },
};
</script>
```

You can read more about vuex-map-fields on my blog: [How to Handle Multi-row Forms with Vue, Vuex and vuex-map-fields](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/how-to-handle-multi-row-forms-with-vue-vuex-and-vuex-map-fields/)

Comment: man, your 'little tool' has saved a lot of programmers, thanks for your dedication

Comment: What impact does the project have on the overall store performance? Is it just a syntactic sugar for binding properties or does it also manage to alleviate frequent store accesses?

Answer (score 4):

I would use deep watchers for this and have all fields in a object, you could use multiple approaches for saving the data, iterating over Object.keys to store each field with it's variable name in the form object, or storing the entire form, whatever you might need.

You could also use `v-model.lazy="form.myfield"` to indicate that you only want the binding to update once the user has left the field.

### Form component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- You can optionally use v-model.lazy="form.field1" to only update once user has exited the field or pressed enter -->
        <input v-model="form.field1" />
        <input v-model.lazy="form.field2" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['value'],

        data: function () {
            return {
                internalForm: {
                    field1: null,
                    field2: null
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            internalForm: {
                handler: function (newValue) {
                // Emit new form object to parent component so we can use v-model there
                this.$emit('input', this.form)
                // Or save form data
                this.handleFormSave(this.form)
                },
                // Tell vue to do a deep watch of entire form object to watch child items in the object
                deep: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Parent component

```
<template>
    <form-component v-model="forms.form1" />
    <submit-button @click="saveAllFormData" />
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                forms: {
                    form1: null // This will be updated when 'input' is emitted 
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            forms: {
                handler: function (newValue) {
                    if (allFormsValid && readyToSave)
                        saveAllFormData(newValue);
                },
                deep: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had headache regarding this probem to.

Vuex doc describes that we need to update store for every field.
It's a loot of typing whatfor?

We make one solution that works.
It based on cloning store object to local one.

```
  //We are passing (vuexstore) 'item' object from parent component:
  //<common-item v-bind:item="item" ....
  props: ['item'],

  // create localItem - this is reactive object for vuex form
  data: () => {
    return {
      localItem: null
    }
  },

  // make clone on created event
  created: function() {
    this.localItem =  this._clone(this.item)
  },

  // watch vuexstore 'item' for changes
  watch: {
    item: function(val) {
      this.localItem = this._clone(this.item)
    }
  },

  // map mutations and update store on event
  methods: {
     ...mapMutations([
      'editItem'
    ]),
    updateItemHandler: function() {
      this.editItem({ item: this._clone(this.localItem) })
    },
    _clone: function(o){
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))
    }
  },
```

Inside form use:

```
 <input v-model="localItem.text" @keyup="updateItemHandler" type="text" class="form-control"></input>
```

I think this is only lack of vuex. There should be much shorter and built in solution.

Comment: I had to rely on something like this too. However, experimenting with putting the local copy in the store too (even though it sounds messy with putting local data to the global store). This is because I can't seem to synchronously create my cloned copy from my component (e.g. in created) only after my api call (vuex action) finishes for the saved form data.