# Search functionality with rest api prevent DDOSing the server

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, debouncing

**The Problem**

I have a search component and component which implements the search component. When I type something in the search bar after 1/2 second of not typing (debounce) the server should be hit and the results should be returned.

The solution i am trying to implement comes from [this post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772629/debounce-computed-properties-getters-in-vue)

**The code**

This leads me to the following code.

I have `search.vue`

```
<template>
    <label for="search">
        <input
                id="search"
                class="w-full py-2 px-1 border-gray-900 border"
                type="text"
                name=":searchTitle"
                v-model="searchFilter"
                :placeholder="searchPlaceholder"
                autocomplete="off"
                v-on:keydown="filteredDataset"
        />
    </label>
</template>
<script>
  import {debounce} from 'lodash';
  export default {
    props: {
      searchPlaceholder: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: ''
      },
      searchName: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: 'search'
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        searchFilter: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      filteredDataset() {
        console.log('event fired');
        this.$emit('searchValue', this.searchFilter);
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

And `product.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="my-4">
            <search
                    search-placeholder=""
                    search-name=""
                    v-on:searchValue="filterValue = $event"
                    v-model="productsFiltered"
            >

            </search>
            <div class="flex w-full py-1 border px-2 my-2" v-for="product in productsFiltered"> (...)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {debounce} from 'lodash';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        products: [],
        filterValue: '',
        filteredProducts: ''
      }
    },
    computed: {
      productsFiltered: {
            get(){
              console.log('getter called');
                return this.filteredProducts;
            },
            set: _.debounce(function(){
              console.log('setter called');
              if (this.filterValue.length < 1) {
                this.filteredProducts = [];
              }

              axios.get(`${apiUrl}search/` + this.filterValue)
                .then(response => {
                  this.products = response.data.products;
                  const filtered = [];
                  const regOption = new RegExp(this.filterValue, 'ig');
                  for (const product of this.products) {
                    if (this.filterValue.length < 1 || product.productname.match(regOption)) {
                      filtered.push(product);
                    }
                  }
                  this.filteredProducts = filtered;
                });


            }, 500)
      }
    },

  }

</script>
```

**The result**
The result is that the setter in the computed property in `product.vue` does not get called and no data is fetched from the server. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code block imports `debounce` but does not use it. It also declares a prop, `searchName`, that isn't used. These aren't central issues, but clutter makes it harder to figure out what's going on.

Your second code block uses `v-model` but does not follow the [required conventions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) for getting `v-model` to work with components:

1. the component must take a prop named `value`
2. the component must `emit input` events to signal changes to `value`

You have the component `emit searchValue` events, and handle them with a `v-on` that sets a data item. You seem to expect the `v-model` to call the setter, but as I noted, you haven't hooked it up to do so.

From what's here, you don't even really need to store the input value. You just want to `emit` it when it changes. Here's a demo:

```js
const searchComponent = {
  template: '#search-template',
  props: {
    searchPlaceholder: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filteredDataset(searchFilter) {
      console.log('event fired');
      this.$emit('input', searchFilter);
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      filterValue: '',
      filteredProducts: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    searchComponent
  },
  computed: {
    productsFiltered: {
      get() {
        console.log('getter called');
        return this.filteredProducts;
      },
      set: _.debounce(function() {
        console.log('setter called');
        if (this.filterValue.length < 1) {
          this.filteredProducts = [];
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("This is the axios call");
          this.filteredProducts = ['one','two','three'];
        }, 200);

      }, 500)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<template id="search-template">
    <label for="search">
        <input
            id="search"
            class="w-full py-2 px-1 border-gray-900 border"
            type="text"
            name=":searchTitle"
            :placeholder="searchPlaceholder"
            autocomplete="off"
            @input="filteredDataset"
        />
    </label>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div class="my-4">
    <search-component search-placeholder="enter something" v-model="productsFiltered">

    </search-component>
    <div class="flex w-full py-1 border px-2 my-2" v-for="product in productsFiltered"> (...)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```