# VueJS Computed Property with Lodash Debounce

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, computed-properties, debouncing

I am filtering through an array of large items based on the user input and that becomes slow. So, wanting to implement the Lodash debounce. However, the debounce isn't affecting anything.

The following is the search input field in HTML where the user types to filter through the array.

```html
<input v-model="search" type="text"/>
```

In the following, I am looping through the `filteredIcons` computed property to show the items.

```html
<section v-if="icons.length">
  <button v-for="(icon, index) in filteredIcons" :key="index">
    <span v-html="icon.icon"></span>
    <span v-text="icon.name"></span>
  </button>
</section>
```

And this is where the `icons` large array and filtering through the computed property.

```js
import { debounce } from "lodash";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      icons: [
               {
                 "author":"svg",
                 "icon":"<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\"><path d=\"M13 16v5a1 1 0 01-1 1H9l-3-6a2 2 0 01-2-2 2 2 0 01-2-2v-2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2 0-1.1.9-2 2-2h7.59l4-4H20a2 2 0 012 2v14a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2.41l-4-4H13zm0-2h1.41l4 4H20V4h-1.59l-4 4H13v6zm-2 0V8H6v2H4v2h2v2h5zm0 2H8.24l2 4H11v-4z\"/></svg>",
                 "name":"icon-announcement.svg"
               },
               {
                 "author":"svg",
                 "icon":"<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\"><path d=\"M20 9v10a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2V9a2 2 0 01-2-2V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h16a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2zm0-2V5H4v2h16zM6 9v10h12V9H6zm4 2h4a1 1 0 010 2h-4a1 1 0 010-2z\"/></svg>",
                 "name":"icon-archive.svg"
               }
             ],
      search: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredIcons: {
      get() {
        return this.icons;
      },
      set: debounce(function() {
        this.icons = this.icons.filter(icon => {
          icon.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
        });
      }, 500)
    }
  }
}
```

I am struggling to understand why this isn't working and what would be the best way to go about filtering through a large data items in an array by implementing the debounce. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The computed prop's setter isn't actually setting anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debounce computed properties/getters in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772629/debounce-computed-properties-getters-in-vue)

Comment: @tony19 It doesn't work when I set the `this.icons` from the setter. I must be doing something silly.

@EricGuan It doesn't.

Comment: Your filter function isn't returning the result of `String#includes`, so the filter would return an empty array.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to be setting `this.icons` in a computed setter, especially when you don't make use of the incoming value at all. Where do you set `filteredIcons`? Shouldn't that just be a readonly prop? It would be more logical for `filteredIcons` to have a getter that returns the result of the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter function is not returning the result of `String#includes`, which results in all items not matching the filter, leading to an empty array. You could either add a `return` keyword to return the result:

```js
const filteredIcons = this.icons.filter(icon => {
  return icon.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
})
```

...or you could remove the brackets and semicolon:

```js
const filteredIcons = this.icons.filter(icon => icon.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))
```

Also, the debounce should be occurring on the user input; not on the computed setter. I would use a [`watcher`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the input's `v-model` (i.e., `search`), and then debounce the result:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    search: {
      handler(search) {
        this.setIconsDebounced(search)
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setIconsDebounced: _.debounce(function(search) {
      this.filteredIcons = this.icons.filter(/*...*/)
    }, 500)
  }
}
```

That eliminates the need for the computed prop, but you still need a variable to hold the filtered icons, so declare one in your data props:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filteredIcons: []
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-paper-wod9x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

Comment: When setting a watcher and `setIconsDebounced` method, removing the search keyword through delete key from keyboard doesn't update the `icons[]` array anymore. It just stays to whatever items it found in the first place for the search term.

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction?

Comment: Created a sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ptolemy-4ttvv where you can reproduce the issue. If you search for `announcement`, you'll see the relevant item. When you remove the search term from the input field to search something else, you'll see nothing is showing and the `icons[]` array is empty.

Comment: Ah, that's because the `icons` array is replaced in `setIconsDebounced`. Use another variable to hold the filtered icons, and make the watcher immediate: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-paper-wod9x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark